# Pass string with pipe as an argument to powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute a powershell script and we pass a password as an argument, the problem is that the password has a pipe on it (among other special chars), something like this:

```
myPowershellScript.ps1 param1 pa$$`w\|ord param3
```

This password is stored in a variable in the ps script and used in a WinSCP session.

I am getting a lot of "ord is not recognized as a internal or external command"

Already tested single quotes, double quotes, caret (^)...

Comment: ``'pa$$`w\|ord'``, i.e. a single-quoted argument, works in principle: your `.ps1` file then receives verbatim ``pa$$`w\|ord``. If that doesn't work for you, the problem must be in how you use that argument _inside_ your script: please [edit] your question to show the relevant command(s).

Comment: Are you calling this script from within PowerShell, or from somewhere else (cmd, run..., schedule task etc.?)

Comment: I am calling this from powershell console

Comment: In that case all you need is single-quotes, as @mklement0 points out. Show us `myPowerShellScript.ps1` :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses, the problem is that I store that value in a variable. Fixed by triple escaping the pipe.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved the problem - perhaps you can share it in the form of an answer to help future readers? However, please make sure to include details of the command in which you use the escaped value, because from the current form of your question it isn't clear where and why it is needed (passing a _variable_ that contains verbatim ``pa$$`w\|ord`` isn't a problem per se).